# ANDROID - How to make a custom layout appear under the marker?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, layout, view

I have to make a layout/view appearing under the marker:
[image: pic]

How can I achieve this? Is there any particular library, that could help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jQuery dialogs? - http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: I need it for android app, not for website